# Are anonymous functions allowed?

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, anonymous-function

Both Eclipse and NetBeans throw errors about the use of anonymous functions. The error in NetBeans says `The language feature not compatible with PHP version indicated in project settings`

The code works but the IDEs doesn't seem to like it.

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NetBeans: in the project settings, set the PHP version to 5.3

Comment: Brilliant! Any idea how to set the PHP version for files that don't belong to any projects?

Answer (score 10):

Same for Eclipse. In Project Properties, set PHP Interpreter to 5.3.

Also see

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation/Execution_Environment
- http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/release-notes/pdt2_1.php